# Loading JAR dependencies into memory

Tags: java, build

If i have 3 jars for example :
(`a.jar` depends on `c.jar`) and (`b.jar` depends also on `c.jar`).

`a.jar` and `b.jar` are built independently with its dependencies in only one package.

What happen when i run both `a.jar` and `b.jar` and loading to memory?

Does the dependencies loaded twice into the memory or just once because they are the same libraries version?

Comment: What does “run both `a.jar` and `b.jar`” mean?  Are you running them as separate Java processes?

Comment: I mean running both from command line each one in a separate command line interface so both running at the same time and live until i close them

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run Java, you start a new process with its own memory.

I seem to recall there was an effort underway to have all Java SE core classes from multiple processes loaded into the same native memory space;  I don’t know if that has been implemented.

Regardless, library .jars will always be independently loaded by each Java process, in that process’s memory.  However, the entire .jar is not necessarily loaded;  Java loads classes only when references to them are encountered in other code.